# My green card and passport don't have the same date of birth

Tags: usa, passports, paperwork, filipino-citizens, us-residents

I need to travel to the Philippines for a week, my green card date of birth is off by one date. But my passport is correct. Do you think I can go there and come back to the US without any problems?

Comment: Might draw some attention however I don't anticipate you being declined traveling because of this. It is similar to the numerous cases of name misspellings etc that are common. Remember there is more information on your passport/green card than just a birth date which help establish you are the same person.

Answer (score 3):

While it might cause a delay in Immigration as you return, if you have sufficient time before departure, you might want to go ahead and correct your records.

[USCIS has an online tool](https://egov.uscis.gov/e-request/displayTypoForm.do) to expedite the process and, in particular, when it contains such a typographic error.

Even if your card is not re-issued in time, the system would reflect that a correction is in process.